# Docker: Install chrome on Windows container using dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-container, docker-image, docker-for-windows

I am trying to install Chrome on my windows container. I've created my docker image with a dockerfile and I would like to install chrome using this dockerfile. I've tried with the following command

```
RUN apt-get update -qqy \
&& apt-get -qqy install \
xvfb \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/apt/*
```

but I have an error (I think it's because I am on windows container and this command is only for unbutu container...) :

```
'apt-get' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

is there any way to install chrome in a windows container? Or any command to replace 'apt-get' ?

Thanks.

Comment: You might take a look here: https://chocolatey.org/

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your comment, I took a look at chocolatey and I may have found a solution, here is an extract of my code where I use chocolatey :                                             
      `RUN powershell -Command iex ((new-object 
      net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'));
      RUN choco install -y googlechrome                `                                                         But I have an error at the end : The command `'cmd /S /C choco install -y googlechrome' returned a non-zero code: 4294967295`

Comment: can you try `choco install googlechrome --ignore-checksums`

Comment: can I ask why are you trying to install Chrome (or anything with GUI for that matter) on a Windows Container? Or is it just for Chrome Headless?

Answer (score 7):

Here's a dockerfile I use to install headless chrome into an aspnet 4.5 image.  Enjoy.

```
# extending the `microsoft/aspnet` image.
FROM microsoft/aspnet

RUN echo 'pull down choco'
RUN powershell -Command Install-PackageProvider -name chocolatey -Force
RUN powershell -Command Set-PackageSource -Name chocolatey -Trusted

RUN powershell -Command Get-PackageSource

RUN echo 'install chrome via choco'
RUN powershell -Command Install-Package GoogleChrome -MinimumVersion 74
```

Another possible route.  Copy all your installers into an 'installer directory' next to your dockerfile.  Then copy them in and run them manually.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
RUN mkdir installers 
COPY ./installers/ /installers
RUN ["c:/installers/ChromeStandaloneSetup64.exe", "/silent", "/install"]
RUN ["c:/installers/Firefox Setup 66.0.3.exe", "-ms"]
```

Hope this helps...
Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Joe. `-RequiredVersion 73` (currently out of date) doesn't work with this approach, so not sure that any switch will matter here.  Have a way to install a specific version? Looks like chocolatey always installs the msi (which is always installs latest)

Comment: For older versions of chrome, [see instructions here](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium). So one would probably need to also disable the google update services a la `Get-Service gupdate* | Stop-Service` after a less pretty/easy install of an older version.

Comment: @SubjectiveReality - what about using -MinimumVersion 73 -MaximumVersion 73 ?  I can't test here as our proxies fry me at the moment.

Comment: I don't think it will work per the notes on [chocolatey's install url for v73](https://chocolatey.org/packages/GoogleChrome/73.0.3683.86)... `This package always installs the latest version of Google Chrome, regardless of the version specified in the package. Google does not officially offer older versions of Chrome for download.`

Comment: You could find the installer for 73, put it into a 'side directory' then push that into your image?  I had to do this today due to some proxy issues.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
RUN mkdir installers
 
COPY ./installers/ /installers

RUN ["c:/installers/ChromeStandaloneSetup64.exe", "/silent", "/install"]

RUN ["c:/installers/Firefox Setup 66.0.3.exe", "-ms"]

Comment: Where did you find the installer for 73?  I went with copying in a powershell script to the image to run ` $Parameters = @{
    generation = '1548376840035005'
    alt = 'media'
}

$targetZip = "$PSScriptRoot\chrome.zip"
$targetPath = "$PSScriptRoot\chrome"

Invoke-WebRequest "https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/chromium-browser-snapshots/o/Win%2F625885%2Fchrome-win.zip" `
    -Body $Parameters -Method Get -OutFile $targetZip

Expand-Archive -Path $targetZip -DestinationPath $targetPath`

Comment: Good coverage of that here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54927496/how-to-download-older-versions-of-chrome-from-a-google-offical-site .  Tis a nightmare.  I would personally start saving off old installers.

Comment: Yeah, saw that too. As many problems as I've seen with chromedriver recently, I'm starting to take a hard look at cypress.io for the longer-term

Comment: jmeter or testcafe?  had some roughs with cypress.