# Chrome shortcut with --incognito and --app ="URL" in target, not working after the latest update

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

Previously before the 89 version update of google chrome, we had a custom shortcut with --incognito --App="URL" in the target properties and it was working well as needed in minimal view incognito mode.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --incognito --App="URL"

but after the update that shortcut no longer works in incognito mode, I tried to create a new shortcut but still no way I could bring back incognito mode into the minimal app view but the target info is completely changed and shows something like below.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome_proxy.exe"  --profile-directory="Profile 3" --app-id=mfcokkkilpmk

I tried to add -incognito command but didn't help doesn't bring back requirements.

Please help out. I really appreciate your suggestions and solutions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I took older version of Chrome, created portable application and disabled its updating. Please, have a look to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54927496/how-to-download-older-versions-of-chrome-from-a-google-official-site) how to find older releases of Chromium. I used second answer with GitHub repo with list of all releases.