# Is it okay to substitute Chromium for Chrome in my Selenium tests?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, chromium, selenium-grid

I currently have a Dockerized Selenium Grid 4 setup with some Chrome nodes and have been trying to figure out how to configure the nodes to use older Chrome versions. I haven't had much luck, but have recently discovered that it's possible to use Chromium nodes on Selenium Grid with this [fork](https://github.com/seleniumhq-community/docker-seleniarm). This appeals to me because older versions of Chromium are [publicly available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54927497/17450359), while older versions of Chrome are not.

Is it safe to assume that running tests on an older Chromium version would be equivalent to running tests on its respective Chrome version? Given that Chromium and Chrome use the same JavaScript engine, and since my tests are just checking for JavaScript errors on a given website, I thought that using Chromium instead of Chrome would be sufficient for my use case.

Does anyone have any insight on this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1) _okay to substitute Chromium for Chrome in my Selenium tests?_: Yes. 2) _use older Chrome versions_: Possibly **not**

Comment: @undetectedSelenium I see.. I've tried installing an older Chromium version via apt-get but got `E: Version '<sample_stable_version>-1' for 'chromium' was not found`.I know there are chromium packages available online (https://chromium.cypress.io/), but I'm not sure how to integrate it into a Selenium node image. Do you have any thoughts on this? I've posted an issue on this that might provide some more context: https://github.com/seleniumhq-community/docker-seleniarm/issues/15