# How do I list all prefixes from an AWS S3 environment over http?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

I was looking to discover all available prefixes at https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots, but I can't seem to find documentation on listing AWS S3 prefixes. I found plenty of documentation on how to list all bucketitems given a prefix, but not how to list all prefixes.

[I found documentation on an LS command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/ls.html), but I have no idea what the intended use is. I think it is for some kind of AWS management console. I am more looking for a RESTful API that I can implement as an XHR request in JavaScript or PowerShell.

I believe that storage API is the bucket for all Chromium builds ever built by the chromium developer team. According to the response from that URL, it uses the AWS S3 API.

[Google's cloud storage API also seems to hint at the fact that it uses AWS's S3 API.](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/overview)

Comment: What is that link? Is it just a file you are sharing, or do you want to parse that actual page?

Comment: Do you want to do it via the AWS CLI, or programmatically?

Comment: You can just use the CLI with something like `aws --no-sign-request --endpoint https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/ s3 ls s3://chromium-browser-snapshots`, or read up on [`ListObjects`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjects.html) and use the `delimiter=/` option, though it may take more than one call to get a complete list.

Comment: programmatically. I was trying to generate a list of download links in NodeJS or PowerShell for all files stored on that storage API, though I beginning to think that prefixes may just be search patterns to limit the listed buckets. I believe that storage API is the bucket for all Chromium builds ever built by the chromium developer team.

Comment: I am very unfamiliar with AWS and google's storage APIs, so my questions and comments may be out of inexperience.

Comment: Then just load `https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots?delimiter=/`, and parse the XML.  If `IsTruncated` is ever True, you'll need to call again to get a complete list.

Comment: @AnonCoward if you can somehow put that into an answer, I'll go ahead and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core the of the REST API that S3 and S3 compatible systems use is documented [by AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjects.html).

For the case of getting prefixes, you can call it with a call like:

```
https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots?delimiter=/
```

Which returns an XML document like:

```
<ListBucketResult xmlns="http://doc.s3.amazonaws.com/2006-03-01">
    <Name>chromium-browser-snapshots</Name>
    <Prefix/>
    <Marker/>
    <NextMarker>Android/</NextMarker>
    <MaxKeys>1</MaxKeys>
    <Delimiter>/</Delimiter>
    <IsTruncated>true</IsTruncated>
    <Contents>
        <Key>index-new.html</Key>
        <Generation>1407426113710000</Generation>
        <MetaGeneration>1</MetaGeneration>
        <LastModified>2014-08-07T15:41:53.709Z</LastModified>
        <ETag>"e5ff54658e153a3305d563e99f3e18d8"</ETag>
        <Size>15137</Size>
    </Contents>
    <CommonPrefixes>
        <Prefix>Android/</Prefix>
    </CommonPrefixes>
</ListBucketResult>
```

There may be one more more `CommonPrefixes/Prefix` nodes with the common prefixes.  And there may be one more `Contents/Key` items with the objects that do not share a common prefix.  If the `IsTruncated` node is set to `true`, then you will need to perform another request with the contents of `NextMarker` as the `marker` value:

```
https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots?delimiter=/&marker=Android/
```

Note that you can't simply blindly pass the value from NextMarker and use it in the URL, you will need to decode it's value, either with a library, or manually parsing it out to ensure that you decode any XML entities, and then encode the value use standard URL encoding rules.

Finally, this ignores the rules for performing signed requests.  For open buckets like this one in the question, this doesn't matter, but for most S3 buckets, you will need to [follow the documentation to sign a request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-signing.html).

Answer (score 2):

When you list the contents of a bucket using `ListObjects()` and pass a `Delimiter`, S3 will return a list of `CommonPrefixes`:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket MYBUCKET --delimiter '/' --query 'CommonPrefixes[]' --output text
```

This will show a list of all Prefixes before the first `/`.

If you want to list ALL prefixes in the bucket (without recursively going through each prefix and making the above call), the easiest method is to **retrieve all objects keys** and then just remove everything after the last slash in an object key.

Something like:

```py
import boto3

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')

prefixes = set()

for object in s3_resource.Bucket('j-stack-ver').objects.all():
    key = object.key
    if '/' in key:
        last_slash = key.rfind('/')
        prefixes.add(key[:last_slash + 1])

print(sorted(prefixes))
```

Comment: Thank you. My only remark is that I was looking for a REST API. I believe that [Anon Coward had mentioned the REST counterpart to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76106218/how-do-i-list-all-prefixes-from-an-aws-s3-environment-over-http/76106290#comment134219720_76106218). However, I do appreciate the python example!