# ChromeDriver Timeout - how do I fix it?

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a problem when starting ChromeDriver, after starting it opens the chrome and after 1 minute of an exception.

It is stopping right on the instance of ChromeDriver

Can you help me?

OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:5001/session timed out after 60 seconds.'

```
ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.Port = 5001;

using (var driver = new ChromeDriver(service))
{
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://testing-ground.scraping.pro/login");
    var userNameField = driver.FindElementById("usr");
    var userPassField = driver.FindElementById("pwd");
    var loginButton = driver.FindElementById("//input[@value='Login']");
    userNameField.SendKeys("admin");
    userNameField.SendKeys("12345");
    loginButton.Click();

    var result = driver.FindElementByXPath("//div[@div='case_login']/h3").Text;
    File.WriteAllText("result.txt", result);

    driver.GetScreenshot().SaveAsFile("@screen.png", ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);

}
```

Comment: Update the question with the error stack trace

Comment: Similar issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53214937/docker-install-chrome-on-windows-container-using-dockerfile/55884825#55884825